# Building OpenCV for js using Emscripten is failing

Tags: javascript, opencv, mingw, emscripten

I'm trying to build OpenCV from source for JS, but have been running into an emcmake error.

This is the command I'm running:

```
emcmake python C:\OpenCV\opencv-4.7.0\platforms\js\build_js.py --emscripten_dir=C:\Users\magma\emsdk\upstream\emscripten build
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bOqP.png)

I have minGW and cmake installed, and can't figure out what's going wrong here! Originally, building wasn't working because emscripten couldn't be found, so I specified its path with the emscripten_dir. Now, I'm running into this, and haven't been able to figure it out on my own or find any resources that remedy the issue

Comment: Your error message is missing. I see no attachment for it.

Comment: @fmw42 You're right! I fixed that

Comment: please do not post images of code or error messages. It is too hard to read or test.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try it on Ubuntu container. Opencv must not support this build on windows.

İf you want pass this error try use **Emscripten 2.0.10** version. But I think you will get different errors.